# Realmのテーブル構造（モデルクラス）変更について

Tags: android, realm

Android、Realm0.83.1で開発をしております。

アプリアップデート時、Realmのテーブル構造（モデルクラス）を変更すると、アプリ起動時にRealmがエラーを出力してクラッシュします。
Realmでは`alter table`のようなテーブル構造（モデルクラス）の変更はできないのでしょうか？

以下がエラーログです。

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
   at io.realm.BaseRealm.migrateRealm(BaseRealm.java:568)
   at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1064)
   at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1053)
   at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:253)
   at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:219)
   at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:182)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmの中の人に教えてもらいました！

[Migration](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/v0.84.1/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java)クラスを使うとバージョンごとの管理ができます

Comment: 回答を承認して頂けるとありがたいです。回答の横のチェックマークをクリックすると回答を承認できます。